# Django Base Page is blank

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-inheritance

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm1mokevMWk&t=2044s&ab_channel=TechWithTim) tutorial to learn Django and I've followed part 4 as in the video, but when I reload my page, it's always blank. I've looked at other posts that were also experiencing a blank page, but they don't address my issue and are very old.

Some more info: I'm using Django 4.1.4, all the files are appropriately saved and named like in the video and there are no errors in the terminal

This is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import ToDoList, Item
# Create your views here.

def index(response, id):
    ls = ToDoList.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(response, 'main/base.html', {})

def home(response):
    return render(response, 'main/home.html', {})
```

base.html:

```
<html>  
<head>
    
    <title> My Website </title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <p> Base Template</p>
    <h1> HELLO </h1>
    
</body>
</html>
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
```

I don't know if this issue is caused by a mistake I'm not finding or a version error.

[image: 2]

This is a picture of my folders.

Comment: getting any errors?

Comment: No, there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

urls.py (in "main" folder) must contain:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("<int:id>", views.index, name="index"),
    path("", views.home, name="home"),
]
```

but urls.py (in "mysite" folder) must contain:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("main.urls")),
]
```

Also base.html and home.html must be in main->templates->main folder
Dont forget to add this in mysite->settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'main.apps.MainConfig', #this string
]
```

After this make `python manage.py runserver` and open in browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/
But this is a blind parsing, if you wrote what error you have in the terminal, it would be easier to figure out what the specific reason is

Comment: There's no actual error that pops up in the terminal, so I can't trace back to my mistake. I've already done this, but it still doesn't work. Also, when I just try to display the base template on the home page, that doesn't work either, so I think something has to be wrong with it.